# "Normal scoped producer method may not return null" error when Injecting RoutingContext into Service class and testing Service class with InjectSpy

Tags: java, vert.x, quarkus

I have a basic Service class that injects `RoutingContext` in order for me to retrieve IP Address and Host information from my client:

***BasicService.java***

```
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@ApplicationScoped
public class BasicService {

  @Inject
  RoutingContext context;

  // Uses injected RoutingContext to retrieve info for logging purposes
  public Uni<ArrayList<String>> simpleFunction() {
    
    // basic usage of RoutingContext (For reproducing error)
    System.out.println(context.request().remoteAddress().host());
    
    // other stuff for service class
  }
}
```

I have a test class that injects a spy for my service class and calls my function:

***BasicServiceUnitTest.java***

```
import io.quarkus.test.TestTransaction;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.InjectSpy;
import pkg.to.BasicService;

@QuarkusTest
@TestTransaction
public class BasicServiceUnitTest {

  @InjectSpy
  BasicService service;

  @Test
  public void testSimpleFunction() {

    Uni<ArrayList<String>> result = service.simpleFunction();

  }
}
```

I get an error saying `javax.enterprise.inject.IllegalProductException: Normal scoped producer method may not return null: io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.CurrentVertxRequest.getCurrent()`

Any thoughts or solutions on how I can resolve this? I'm thinking since it's injecting a mocked object of my service class it doesn't have any 'real' RoutingContext to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that won't work.

`RoutingContext` is tied to an HTTP request, so you can't use it like that with a test.

To mock thaf type, you would need to explicitly create the CDI bean yourself using something like https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#cdi-alternative-mechanism

Comment: Hmm.. I see, not sure if this is the right question/approach - would there be a way to I guess mock a RoutingContext during my unit test?